# C#, web services,soap : System.InvalidOperationException: Le type System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Magasin_xxx was unexpected

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I have a webservice in C# which call a sql server database.
This web service is tested by a Test project in visual studio.

I added the web service reference in the test project, and call it from my test method like this:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void testBaseConstruiteDansSetUp()
    {


        //int result5 = service5.Multiply(2, 5);
        //Assert.AreEqual(10, result5);
        Market5.Magasin[] magasins = Service5.getMagasins();
        //Assert.AreEqual(1, sm.Magasins.Length);
        Assert.AreEqual(2, magasins[0].Rayons[0].Produits.Length);


    }
```

The service method getMagasins() call generates at launch the following error:

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException:
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: the server wasn't able to
>   treat the demand. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: error at the
>   XML file generation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: the type
>   System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Magasin_1337937A1EAAA5313EBABDF20700EF9CF8D2AFFD23D16247FDF34BB84D67C50F
>   wasn't expected. use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute  to
>   specify types that aren't statically known.

please note  that I use entity framework in a model project, and the EF project is a reference in the web service (in fact an ASP .NET project with an ASMX file) and in the test project.

here is the web service getMagasins() method:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public List<Magasin> getMagasins()
    {
        using (var ctx = new MarketContext("sqlserverPersonalId"))
        {
            //new MyDataInitializer().InitializeDatabase(ctx);

            var produitMagasin = new ProduitMagasin() { Nom = "Pommes", Quantite = 10 };
            ctx.ProduitsMagasin.Add(produitMagasin);

            var rayon1 = new Rayon() { Nom = "Fruits & Légumes2", Produits = new List<ProduitMagasin> { produitMagasin } };
            ctx.Rayons.Add(rayon1);
            ctx.SaveChanges();

        }

        //récupération en base
        DbSet<Magasin> dbMagasins = null;
        List<Magasin> magasins = new List<Magasin>();


        using (var ctx2 = new MarketContext("sqlserverPersonalId"))
        {
            dbMagasins = ctx2.Magasins;
            foreach (Magasin mg in dbMagasins)
            {
                magasins.Add(mg);
            }
        }

    return magasins;
    }

}
```

please note that in the test method, the Market5.Magasins is needed, and I had to change the Model.Magasin type to Market5.Magasin : the program uses the Magasin type provided by the service and not the one provided by the Model project.

here is the return structure of the getMagasins() method:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <getMagasinsResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <getMagasinsResult>
        <Magasin>
          <MagasinId>int</MagasinId>
          <Rayons>
            <Rayon xsi:nil="true" />
            <Rayon xsi:nil="true" />
          </Rayons>
        </Magasin>
        <Magasin>
          <MagasinId>int</MagasinId>
          <Rayons>
            <Rayon xsi:nil="true" />
            <Rayon xsi:nil="true" />
          </Rayons>
        </Magasin>
      </getMagasinsResult>
    </getMagasinsResponse>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

how to solve this error?

thank you.

ps: here is in the Model project the Magasin class:

```
namespace Model
{
    [Table("Magasin")]
    public class Magasin
    {
        [Key]
        public int MagasinId { set; get; }

        public virtual List<Rayon> Rayons { set; get; }


    }
}
```

Comment: The format of the return data is not valid.  One of the headers in the http request asked for a mode that was not valid and server was not able to return data in requested format.  It looks like you got a response of 200 OK and you got results which means the server returned data in a default mode and ignored the error and then gave an exception even though data was returned.

Comment: I made you doing an error : the soap answer was produced by a browser,it is not the service answer. anyway, I agree to your idea : the object type in the answer is the root of the evil. but why? didn't see why

Comment: data types in the code seem alright

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare the headers in 1st request of the working and non working.  Then make your c# headers look like working request.  The default headers in Net Library are not the same.

Comment: well, with my browser I can only see the structure of the answer, but when I try to call the method, I get the same error as seen in visual studio.

Comment: You should be able to capture with the sniffer the browser request.  You may want to delete cookies and try again.  The default browser in the request may be set wrong in the service.  Guessing doesn't usually work.  Using sniffer is much better.

Comment: I decided to use WCF instead of ASP.NET projects

Comment: Are you still getting exception?

Comment: well, I totally stopped this project.sorry. I'm on WCF project.